# Office PIA and .NET framework version compatibility 

Tags: .net, pia

I use Office Primary Interop Assemblies (PIA) for Microsoft Office 2003 and 2007. On the download page of PIA, it is mentioned that .NET framework 1.1 is required.

I want to know if the requirement of version 1.1 - is it minimum version that is required? Or is it strict requirement.

In other words, if I have .NET version 2.0 or 3 or 3.5 and don't have 1.1 installed then, will the PIAs work fine or do PIAs require 1.1 version irrespective of what higher version you have?

Answer (score 0):

Office PIA's work with framework version 2.0 and higher.